# converting current webpages to pdf file using javascript or c#

Tags: asp.net

Is there any possible to convert current webpage to pdf file using javascript or c# in asp.net? for print option i am loading one aspx page to pop window using xslt file. From popup window how to convert that webpage to pdf file

Comment: take a look at these two solutions: [link1](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/414219/Convert-webpage-to-pdf) and [link2](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/16126/convert-web-pageaspx-page-to-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach is to simply install some pdf printer software an just send this page to this printer.

http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp

Comment: without installing other third party we can't convert webpage to PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy problem. I have tried different libraries to do this in code, but they are usually dependent on external programs installed on the server, or too cumbersome to work with. The last time I had to do this, I had narrowed it down to two:

- [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)
- [Pechkin](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin)

The first is a library, which is a port of the Java iText to .NET. It allows you to compose PDF files in code, but is not specifically targeted to converting from HTML to PDF. You would have to use its API to render the page in memory, convert it, and then return to the user.

The other library is a wrapper around a command-line tool. That tool uses a headless webkit browser to open html and convert to PDF. The command-line tool itself is good, but you would still need to render the HTML and pass it.

At the end, I solved my problem in Ruby and didn't really use any of these, but I think they are your best bet. Unless of course you want to buy a separate product, in which case there may be better ones out there.

Comment: Yes your right but i tried with iTextSharp, In that showing error in  this.Page.RenderControl(hw).. I know that need to solve this problem by giving enableviewstate is false. but if i give this in aspx my DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged was not working.. is there any solution for this??